# AWS RDS rename database name

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a database created with RDS and I want to rename it. But whenever I try to modify it through the AWS console, the option for the database name is gone.

[image]

And when I try it through the shell, it's showing an error.

[image]

I just need to rename the DB name from `postgrestestdatabase` to a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS Management console can be used to create the *initial* database, but after that you'll need to interact with the database directly to manipulate databases.

The error message is saying `current database cannot be renamed`.

Therefore, try this:

- Connect to a *different* database (if no other databases exist, create one first)
- Try your `ALTER DATABASE ... RENAME`
- Connect to the renamed database
- Optional: Delete the database you created earlier

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can change the DB in PostgreSQL :

```
postgres=> alter database "TSTABC" rename to "UATABC";
```

But AWS console still shows the original name(TSTABC) not the new name. This is the same effect even after restarting the whole cluster.

Comment: I removed the more obviously non-answering part. I am not sure however, that you actually tried to answer the question with the part which I left. Please check. Please see [answer] and note that in all cases of clicking "Post Your Answer" you should actually try to answer the question at the top of the page. If you did not try to answer at all please delete this post.